# Create label using most frequent value / weight

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, containing results of an ensemble classification model. This gives me for each prediction a `Label` and a `Conf`.

Now I want to create the `Label_Final` by the following logical:

- Most frequent value exists --> take this one
- Two most frequent values --> take the one with larger `Conf` sum
- No most frequent value --> take the one with largest `Conf`
- No most frequent value and more than one `Conf` with same value, just take one (random/first, doesn't matter)

---

Let assume the data lookes like:

```
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
|    | Label1   |   Conf1 | Label2   |   Conf2 | Label3   |   Conf3 | Label4   |   Conf4 |
|----+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------|
|  0 | Class1   |     0.9 | Class2   |     0.8 | Class2   |     0.8 | Class2   |     0.8 |
|  1 | Class2   |     0.8 | Class2   |     0.2 | Class2   |     0.5 | Class2   |     0.5 |
|  2 | Class1   |     0.7 | Class2   |     0.5 | Class3   |     0.9 | Class4   |     0.8 |
|  3 | Class4   |     0.6 | Class4   |     0.2 | Class3   |     0.4 | Class3   |     0.2 |
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

The calculation would be:

- `Row[0]`, 3 x `Class2`

  - --> take `Class2`
- `Row[1]`, 4 x `Class2`

  - --> take `Class2`
- `Row[2]`, no most frequent one

  - highest `Conf` is `0.9`
  - --> take `Class3`
- `Row[3]`, 2 x `Class3` & 2 x `Class4`

  - `Class4` `Conf` = `0.6 + 0.2 = 0.8`
  - `Class3` `Conf` = `0.4 + 0.2 = 0.6`
  - --> take `Class4`

Because I need to look at the `Conf` to select the `Label` I don't know how to solve it with `pd.mode()` and `pd.nunique()` - I don't even know if it's possible with this functions. Can somebody help?

---

**MWE**

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Label1":["Class1", "Class2", "Class3", "Class4"],
    "Conf1":[0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6],
    "Label2":["Class2", "Class2", "Class2", "Class4"],
    "Conf2":[0.8,0.2,0.5,0.2],
    "Label3":["Class2", "Class2", "Class3", "Class3"],
    "Conf3":[0.8,0.5,0.9,0.4],
    "Label4":["Class2", "Class2", "Class3", "Class3"],
    "Conf4":[0.8,0.5,0.8,0.2]
})
df["Label_Final"] = ["Class2", "Class2", "Class3", "Class4"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cound reshape to longer, then count the number of classes, and sum the confs, Finally sort by these two in a descending order then select the first one in each case.

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['Label', 'Conf'], 'index', 'grp')
   .reset_index().groupby(['index', 'Label'])
   .agg(count=('Label', 'count'), Conf=('Conf', 'sum'))
   .reset_index().sort_values(['count', 'Conf'], ascending = [False, False])
   .groupby('index').head(1).rename(columns = {'Label':'Final_Label'})
   .merge(df.reset_index(), on='index', how='right'))

   index Final_Label  count  Conf  Label1  ...  Conf2  Label3  Conf3  Label4  Conf4
0      1      Class2      3   2.4  Class1  ...    0.8  Class2    0.8  Class2    0.8
1      2      Class2      4   2.0  Class2  ...    0.2  Class2    0.5  Class2    0.5
2      3      Class3      1   0.9  Class1  ...    0.5  Class3    0.9  Class4    0.8
3      4      Class4      2   0.8  Class4  ...    0.2  Class3    0.4  Class3    0.2
```